# Unity application menus and title bar issue with Wine applications

Tags: 11.04, unity, wine, appmenu

At the moment, I get two title bars for maximized applications which run through Wine.

Is there a way to get rid of one of them (the "non-unity" one, obviously)?

Is there a way to get the application menu for Wine applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Ad title bars: this is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/778595).

  What works for me: drag the window to the top edge to trigger Compiz' Grid plugin, which then maximizes the window.
- Ad application menus: I don't think that's supposed to work right now.